# Apple Mach-O Linker Error for arm64

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I know there are a few topics on this, but none seem to do the trick;

I'm testing to the device and I get 5 errors, all Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. The code looks likes this;

Any thoughts? I've tried to play around with the Active Architecture but nothing seems to work.

Thank you!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libCordova.a(CDVURLProtocol.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      ___30-[CDVURLProtocol startLoading]_block_invoke in libCordova.a(CDVURLProtocol.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocation", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_CLLocation_$_JSONMethods in libCordova.a(CDVShared.o)
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      ___30-[CDVURLProtocol startLoading]_block_invoke in libCordova.a(CDVURLProtocol.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Could you copy/paste the code instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: I've updated it, I can add anything else if needed

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your errors  I think you need to import some frameworks , Just try to import following frameworks :

1. CoreLocation
2. ALAssetsLibrary
3. MobileCoreServices.framework

Comment: would i import these frameworks in to the cordova library binary?

Comment: i added the frameworks but still getting the same errors

Comment: @ynghype:Just added that into your project instead of the cordova lib

Comment: can you clarify just a bit? I appreciate your answer though it sounds like it'll work

Comment: @ynghype: From somewhere in the code you are using some classes which are defined in above frameworks . As you are developing the phonegap application that code might not be your code , however that code may be used in the some phone gap plugin or phone gap library thats why you need to add above frameworks !